# Unexpected $2$ in normalised wavefunction coefficient

Tags: integration, complex-numbers, quantum-mechanics

My course notes have,

> For the particle confined to $x\in[0,a]$, the stationary state wavefunctions are $$\psi(x,t)=\begin{cases}A_n\exp\left(-\frac{i\hbar n^2\pi^2t}{2ma^2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{2\pi x}{a}\right) &\text{if }0<x<a\\0&\text{otherwise,}\end{cases}$$ where $n=1,2,3,\dots$ and $A_n$ are undetermined complex constants.
>
> To normalise $\psi_n(x,t)$ we choose the coefficient $A_n$ so that $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty|\psi_n(x,t)|^2\text{ d}x=\int_0^a|\psi_n(x,t)|^2\text{ d}x=1.$$ Plugging the stationary state wavefunctions in gives $$|A_n|^2=\frac{2}{a},\text{ for all }n=1,2,3,\dots$$

I guess this is a simple question, but where did this $2$ come from? My thinking is
\begin{align}
& \begin{aligned}
|\psi_n(x,t)|^2
& = \left|A_n\exp\left(-\frac{i\hbar n^2\pi^2t}{2ma^2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{2\pi x}{a}\right)\right|^2 && (1) \\
& = |A_n|^2\cdot\left|\exp\left(-\frac{i\hbar n^2\pi^2t}{2ma^2}\right)\right|^2\cdot\left|\sin\left(\frac{2\pi x}{a}\right)\right|^2 && (2) \\
& = |A_n|^2\cdot1\cdot1\text{ (in the complex plane)} && (3) \\
& = |A_n|^2 && (4)
\end{aligned} \\[0.5em]
\therefore\;&\begin{aligned}[t]
1
& = \int_0^a|\psi_n(x,t)|^2\text{ d}x && \hspace{14.25em} (5) \\
& = \int_0^a|A_n|^2\text{ d}x && \hspace{14.25em} (6) \\
& = |A_n|^2a && \hspace{14.25em} (7)
\end{aligned} \\[0.5em]
\therefore\;& |A_n|^2=\frac{1}{a}. \hspace{20.75em} (8)
\end{align}
What's gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you actually attempt the integration of the squared sine in line $(2)$?

$$\begin{align}
\int_{x=0}^a \sin^2 \frac{2\pi x}{a} \, dx &= \int_{u=0}^{\pi} (\sin^2 2u) \frac{a}{\pi} \, du & \left( x = \frac{a}{\pi} u, \quad dx = \frac{a}{\pi} \, du \right) \\
&= \frac{a}{\pi} \left[\frac{u}{2} - \frac{1}{8} \sin 4u \right]_{u=0}^\pi \\
&= \frac{a}{\pi} \frac{\pi}{2} \\
&= \frac{a}{2}.
\end{align}$$

The fact that the complex exponential term has magnitude $1$ is a trivial consequence of the fact that $|e^{i\theta}| = 1$ for any angle $\theta$.

Comment: I didn't. I was mistakenly thinking that on $\mathbb{C}$ we had $|\sin(\theta)|=1\;\forall\;\theta$. Thanks.

Comment: @mjc No worries, these things happen even to the best of us.  I once spent a good hour tracking down a sign error.  I thought I was losing my mind.